# Indexing over the results returned by selenium

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I try to index over results returned by an xpath. For example:

```
xpath = '//a[@id="someID"]'
```

can return a few results. I want to get a list of them. I thought that doing:

```
numOfResults = sel.get_xpath_count(xpath)
l = []
for i in range(1,numOfResults+1):
   l.append(sel.get_text('(%s)[%d]'%(xpath, i)))
```

would work because doing something similar with firefox's Xpath checker works:

```
(//a[@id='someID'])[2]
```

returns the 2nd result.

Ideas why the behavior would be different and how to do such a thing with selenium
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you need to tell selenium that you're using xpath:

```
numOfResults = sel.get_xpath_count(xpath)
l = []
for i in range(1,numOfResults+1):
   l.append(sel.get_text(xpath='(%s)[%d]'%(xpath, i)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the xpath `/html/descendant::a[@id="someID"]` You can replace the `/html` with something else that is an ancestor of your links like `id('content')`. You should then be able to locate individual links using `[1]`, `[2]` etc.

From the XPath TR at http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev:

> **NOTE**: The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium you normally do it without the extra brackets so your loop would look like the following

```
numOfResults = sel.get_xpath_count(xpath)
l = []
for i in range(1,numOfResults+1):
   l.append(sel.get_text('%s[%d]'%(xpath, i)))
```

And that will produce a valid XPath in Selenium like `//a[@id='someID'][2]`

Comment: That doesn't work - because it enumerates on the child a-s. Meaning that if you have two a-s matching this xpath and both have a parent div. And both are the first child of that div, then `xpath[1]` will return both links and `xpath[2]` will return none.

Comment: `//a[@id='someID'][1]` should return the first element on the page that is a link with an ID = someID and then `//a[@id='someID'][2]` will return the 2nd element. With that xpath you are using it doesnt care what the parent is. `xpath[1]` will not return an array because it is looking for the first element in an array

Comment: try this: goto http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=google
(or search for google in google)
and look for the xpath `//li//a[1]`. I get all the links and not just the first one.